# Table not found - wrong naming strategy?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I can clearly see with pgAdmin that table "TEST" exists inside public scheme.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST", schema = "public")
public class TestEntity
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    databasePlatform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [TEST]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:67)
```

When I change ddl-auto to 'update' it creates table with "test" name and everything starts to work as expected. The problem is that I think my configuration is fine and it should find "TEST".
Can someone help? Maybe I need to use more specific dialect?

Comment: From my experience, such errors are related to data source definition in application yaml, if your schema is ok.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is a naming strategy, of course.

1. When you explicitly specify a table name, like here `@Table(name = "TEST")` only `PhysicalNamingStrategy` can change it (opposite `ImplicitNamingStrategy`).
2. `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` changes names to lowercase, as you can see from the sources: [SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.java). A code snippet from there:

   `protected Identifier getIdentifier(String name, boolean quoted,
               JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
           if (isCaseInsensitive(jdbcEnvironment)) {
               name = name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
           }
           return new Identifier(name, quoted);
    }`
3. `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` does nothing. So the table name should be `TEST` as you specified. But, looks like, you specified it incorrectly in the `spring-boot` configuration. You should double check the property name.
4. You can also check other properties files (may be you have other jars) for that property value.

Also, just to test, you can try to use `application.properties` with

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your `hibernate` version I guess this could be `hibernate` feature described for example [here](https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3701).

In that case the solution is to change table name to lower case

```
@Table(name = "TEST", schema = "public")
```

to

```
@Table(name = "test", schema = "public")
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/pull/1850).

Depending on your database it might also be possible to have table to be created UPPERCASE by wrapping it with escaped  double quotes.

```
@Table(name = "\"TEST\"", schema = "public")
```

Latter works at least with Postgres.